# is there a substitute malloc and free library on solaris?

Tags: memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, malloc, solaris

I am trying to find memory leaks in a very complicated legacy system that is written in C++/C on the Solaris operating system. the  idea is to log every malloc and free and then postproccess the log.

i was able to write a stub malloc and free function that gets called correctly. the problem is that they dont do anyhing other than log. As a result the sytem crashes

My question is: is they a substitute malloc library that works on solaris that is can call from my stub malloc& free functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just do an LD_PRELOAD of libumem and use UMEM_DEBUG? The manpage for umem_debug should give you more information.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, You should some memory profiling tool but in the absence of the same you can try to implement your own leak detector as you plan to.

You can just call `malloc` and `free` library versions through your wrapper.

Here is a scheme that you may try to implement:

Your wrapper function should implement a functionality wherein your wrapper for `malloc` stores the line number, file name, size requested & address being returned by malloc in a linked list.
How to get filename and line number?
Hint: Use `__FILE__`, `__LINE__`

The `free` wrapper should check the address being sent for freeing against the list and remove the entry from the linked list.

At the end of the program you should print contents of this linked list which gives you leaking memory size, file name and line number from where the buffer was allocated.

**Update:**
**How do you map program `malloc` calls to own wrapper calls without infinite recurssion?**

Through clever Use of Macros!

```
#define malloc(X) my_malloc( X, __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__)

void* my_malloc(size_t size, const char *file, int line, const char *func)
{

    void *p = malloc(size);
    printf ("Allocated = %s, %i, %s, %p[%li]\n", file, line, func, p, size);

    /*Link List functionality goes in here*/

    return p;
}
```

Comment: how do i call malloc and free library versions through my wrapper? wouldn't it cause an infinite recursion? i cant call my wrapper anything other than "malloc".

Comment: @yigal: Updated the answer, it answers your how to Q.

Comment: sadly, that wont work because it requires recompilation of all the source code. Since the code base is huge, i cant do it -  i can only compile a small portion of it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to libumem, I would recommend using Solaris Studio dbx which includes with [RTC](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5257/blahb/index.html), a memory leak detector.